# Probability that a string is corrupt given the chance of individual digits being corrupt

Tags: probability

> A binary sequence of 1’s and 0’s is transmitted from a sender to receiver. Along the way, it is
>   possible for the data to become corrupted, that is, any 1 in the transmitted sequence has a 0.1%
>   chance of being turned into a 0, and any 0 in the transmitted sequence has a 0.01% chance of being
>   turned into a 1. Digits are corrupted no more than once during transmission and the corruption of
>   a specific digit does not influence the corruption of any others. The sequence 010010 was received.
>   What is the probability that this signal is corrupt?

My first approach was to define $D_i$ as the event that the ith digit is corrupted. Then the probability that the signal is corrupt is $P(D_1\cup D_2\cup D_3\cup D_4\cup D_5\cup D_6)$, which is an insanely time-consuming thing to calculate. I know there is a much better approach but I just can't think of it. Maybe it has to do with how I'm defining my events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your formulation. Rather than calculating all the overlapping outcomes in $P(D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3 \cup D_4 \cup D_5 \cup D_6)$, note that the negation of the negation is much easier to calculate: $$1-P(\lnot D_1 \cap \lnot D_2 \cap \lnot D_3 \cap \lnot D_4 \cap \lnot D_5 \cap \lnot D_6)\text{ ,}$$
where the second term is the product of the probabilities of each particular digit not being corrupt.